# What is $\liminf_{x\to y}f(x)$?

Tags: real-analysis

I see what is the $\liminf_{n\to\infty }x_n$ if $(x_n)$ is a sequence, I also see what is $\liminf_{n\to\infty }f_n(x)$ for a sequence of function, but what if $$\liminf_{x\to y}f(x)$$ for a function $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ ?

Would it be something like $$\sup_{\delta}\inf_{|x-y|<\delta}f(x)$$ ?

Comment: That looks reasonable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is

$$\lim_{\delta\to0}\quad\inf_{|x-y|<\delta}\quad f(x)$$

Comment: That looks more reasonable, but I actually think they turn out to be the same in this case.